# Use case for JavaScript Constructor Function

Tags: javascript

Finally decided to spend the time and get a grip on programming with JS rather than just stuffing spaghetti code into script tags at the end of a file. [YDKJS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) is a great resource in my opinion. I have a pretty good understanding of factory patterns, IFFE and how objects and Object.create(...) are used.

One question that I cannot find an answer to is if constructor functions are still used and if so what would be the use case for them? The only reason I ask is because there are years of articles where that was the answer. Seems the idea was to get closer to class based inheritance (pre es6).

Essentially is it a design pattern I should invest time into learning?

Comment: It is mentioned in Kyle Simpson's video that constructors are introduced in ES6 to make it feel like class based as JS itself matures even though they are not.

Comment: He's talking about pre-ES6 constructor functions @Rikin

Comment: "*there are years of articles where that was the answer.*" - the answer to what?

Comment: @Bergi to OOP with JavaScript. For allowing inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: @nerdlyist Well, then that is the use case that you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Of course constructors make sense and are used. Consider the following:

```js
A = function()
{
    this.foo = "bar";
};

A.prototype.printFoo = function()
{
    console.log(this.foo);
};


B = function()
{
    this.foo = "foobar";
};

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);

aInstance = new A();
aInstance.printFoo(); // foo

bInstance = new B();
bInstance.printFoo(); // foobar
```

A bit simplified: When calling a function with the `new` keyword, JS treats it as a constructor and passes an empty object named `this` into it. When assigning the constructor’s return value to a variable, it will contain the `this` object, extended by the properties of the function’s prototype as well as the modifications to `this` which were applied within the constructor. Therefore constructors are extremly useful and necessary in JS.

In ES6, constructors (and class-orientation in general) have become even more prominent; have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes for more.

Answer (score 1):

> Are constructor functions still used?

Yes, of course they are. They are, and will continue to be, the dominant object construction pattern. They are as pervasive as object literals. They have the best performance optimisations in engines, and are used whenever large numbers of instances are needed. And the class pattern with a constructor for initialisation and a prototype for method inheritance is the most convenient pattern you get, with extra simple `class` syntax since ES6.

Comment: Can you clarify "They are, and will continue to be, the dominant object construction pattern"?

Comment: Mostly what would that pattern look like?

Comment: @nerdlyist Those things you mentioned, "*factory patterns, IFFE and Object.create(...)*" all are patterns for constructing objects, and constructor functions are just another one. And the most popular and frequently used one.

Comment: @nerdlyist I thought you already knew what constructor functions are?

Comment: Correct my apologies fleeting thought. I will have to look more into the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor functions are designed to be used with *new* prefix. the new prefix creates a new object based on function's prototype and binds that object to the function's implicit this parameter.

Source: JavaScript the good parts by Douglas Crockford

Comment: Totally know what they are and do. Mostly looking if it is still a design pattern in JS.